# Ввод текста в формате JSON в SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift

Есть функция вывода сообщения

```
self.iotDataManager?.subscribe(toTopic: topic.name, qoS: AWSIoTMQTTQoS(rawValue: topic.QoS)!, messageCallback: { (data) in
        if let message = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let newMessage = MQTTMessageModel()
                newMessage.topic = topic
                newMessage.date = Date()
                newMessage.message = message as String!

                self.messages.insert(newMessage, at: 0)

                self.filterMessages()

                self.messagesTable.reloadData()

                NSLog("get message: \(message)")
```

Как сделать чтобы когда я ввожу сообщение "один":"два" оно выводилось как       один два

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял ваш вопрос, то первое, что приходит в голову:

```
// удаляем '"' из строки
let tmp = message.replacingOccurrences(of: "\"", with: "")

// расщепляем строку на массив строк по разделителю ':'
let arr = tmp.components(separatedBy: ":")

NSLog("get message: \(arr[0]) \(arr[1])")
```